# Blank Screen upon boot, but no GRUB menu!

Tags: installation, live-usb

Thanks and any help would be much appreciated.

- HP Pavillion dv6 notebook: < 6 months old
- i5 processor
- dual integrated graphics
- 8 gb ram
- 750 HDD
- Currently running W7

I have a bootable USB drive 12.04.1 LTS (i know its fine, because it works with any other computer), and i need it to work on my HP notebook. I have already updated my BIOS and changed boot sequence.

I plug in the USB, and wait for my PC to read and initiate the boot. The light on the USB  flickers (a good thing), but then suddenly stops (in other computer, it keeps flickering). At this point, my screen is almost fully black. No cursor, or image of ubuntu logo or even the grub. I tried entering grub: e, alt + cntl +f4, ctl + x -- everything. No response.

Also after about 6 seconds upon reaching the black screen, my laptops, fan, or something go off to quite loud: if that helps.

I read similar issues, but those atleast are able to reach grub; i cannot.

Thx, any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

P.S: im not new to ubuntu, as i have used plenty of ubuntu 10, and had the exact same problem. It worked on everyother computer.

Comment: @Mukund i have Ubuntu 12.04 installed in my bootable usb, i use it in various computers where i access the grub

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: @TomBrossman yes, that one is similar, the major difference is that i already have ubuntu installed on the USB.

Comment: Is this a 'Live USB' or a real install on a USB drive? Also, is it a real hard drive you connect with a USB cable, or is it a USB stick (usually called a thumb drive)? If it's an install to a USB thumb drive it will be terribly slow and you may need to wait longer? Shouldn’t take 10 minutes to boot or anything like that, but it will really be slow, almost un-usable.

Comment: @TomBrossman It is a real install on a USB drive. Yes it is a real "thumbdrive". I am aware that is slow, but still beats Windows. Also, i have been using it for a while and it hasnt caused much trouble on another computer. Maybe its because its 16gb or maybe because im using it on a decent computer. I have waited for > 30 min only change i notice is the fan speed and volume.

Comment: Okay. Since it works with other computers, and since you are allowing extra time for how slow it is, you are back to the 'computer boots to black screen' issue. Wish I could be more help but that is your chief complaint and it sounds like a duplicate to me.

Comment: I didnt think so, as that user was trying to install ubuntu and encountered a blank screen. Me on the other hand, Im trying to boot from a already installed one and am getting a black screen. I think that our symptoms are similar, but problem, different

Answer (score 0):

When I first tried to get into the GRUB menu on my computer, I found holding shift down as soon as the computer was powered and holding it usually opened the GRUB menu. Have you plugged the USB into another computer and checked it for errors?  It is also possible that the boot sequence is wrong, or there was an error when you updated the BIOS. try going into the boot menu, not the BIOS, when you turn your computer on (probably by holding F5) and see if it says boot from USB.

Comment: I have even tried entering the boot options and manually selecting USB drive to boot from: ends up in the same screen. I just tried the shift key thing now, nothing new. I have used the same USB on a dell notebook and acer. It boots up just fine.

Comment: Try running a memory test utility. If the usb works on other computers, the problem is related to the laptop. it could be processor or memory. If you can get into the BIOS, see waht kind of diagnostic tools it has.

Comment: none. It just has 'update' or 'rollback'. I just realised that none of the other computers have dual integrated graphics, my laptop does. Maybe that helps narrow it down

Answer (score 0):

If your bios is legacy boot mode just check if ubuntu could start in Uefi boot mode. I don't know if it will work, sorry if its wrong.